# How can I download an entire website?

Tags: download, website, web

How can I download all pages from a website?

Any platform is fine.

Comment: Check out http://serverfault.com/questions/45096/website-backup-and-download on Server Fault.

Comment: @tnorthcutt, I'm surprised too. If I don't recall awfully wrong, my Wget answer used to be the accepted one, and this looked like a settled thing. I'm not complaining though — all of a sudden the renewed attention gave me more than the bounty's worth of rep. :P

Comment: did you try IDM? http://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website/42379#42379 my post is buried down. What did you find missing in IDM?

Comment: @joe: Might help if you'd give details about what the missing features are...

Comment: [browse-offline.com](http://www.browse-offline.com) can download the complete tree of the web-site so you can ... browse it offline

Comment: @MenelaosVergis browse-offline.com is gone

Comment: Yes, I don't even have the code for that!

Comment: just FYI please scam!!! do not download from https://websitedownloader.io/ it will ask small amount, which will look convincing but downloads just a webpage, does not even work for plain websites.

Comment: Try [Cyotek](https://www.cyotek.com/cyotek-webcopy/downloads) best web page scraper for offline viewing.

Answer (score 426, accepted):

[HTTRACK](https://www.httrack.com/) works like a champ for copying the contents of an entire site.  This tool can even grab the pieces needed to make a website with active code content work offline.  I am amazed at the stuff it can replicate offline.

This program will do all you require of it.

Happy hunting!

Comment: Been using this for years - highly recommended.

Comment: You can also limit the speed of download so you don't use too much bandwidth to the detriment of everyone else.

Comment: Finally this one is bit better than others ;)

Comment: Would this copy the actual ASP code that runs on the server though?

Comment: @Optimal Solutions: No, that's not possible. You'd need access to the servers or the source code for that.

Comment: After trying both httrack and wget for sites with authorization, I have to lean in favor of wget. Could not get httrack to work in those cases.

Comment: Whats the option for authentication?

Comment: what if i try to copy wiki en?

Comment: A nice tutorial for basic use - http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/save-and-backup-websites-with-httrack/

Comment: I would like to download for example the large images from the listings on ebay (the ones that are being shown in each listing) by using the link of the search result. is it possible for someone to tell me the settings for HTTrack that I can use to do that?

Comment: Is this supporting downloading paged contents like mywebsite.com/games?page=1, mywebsite.com/games?page=2 because seems like it keeps overriding of previously created pages and shows only last page. Please advice.

Comment: Does it support cookies (sessions)?

Comment: This is a terrible program. It has great trouble downloading single web-pages, poor control over following links and to what depth, and an absurd download speed limit from last decade. Just use wget, save yourself the pain.

Comment: For **macOS**, use `brew install httrack` and then run it with `httrack`. It has a great menu after that. Easy peezie, lemon squeezie!

Comment: Program has a lot of options, no documentation and seemed to only download a single page.

Comment: 1/2 HTTrack does not work like a champ for me at all. It downloads with 20 KiB/s speed using 1 connection at the same time, downloading only 1 file at the same time. Which renders it unusable for websites with many pages. In my case I have a website with articles on it, then there is a wiki and then there's a forum. In total it has around 30000-50000 pages. It would take me weeks if not months to download it using HTTrack. And there is no way to increase download speed.

Comment: 2/2 I tried to set --disable-security-limits while running httrack from command line, set it in Scan Rules in GUI and in the URL list in GUI. None of these work. I also set the transfer rate to 1000000 which is only 1 MiB/s. And set the maximum connections / second to 10. It still downloads with only 20 KiB/s rate. When I browse the website in my browser, it opens the website instantly(in less than half a second), so it definitely works at a much higher speed than 20 KiB/s. And my speed is 100 Mbit/S, when I download something, it reaches 11.2 MiB/s speed in just a few seconds.

Comment: This application is apparently not able to handle http to https redirects or https pages at all., despite stating otherwise in its FAQ. Maybe it just can't handle the proxy, though.

Comment: This app doesn't work. It leaves links to online pages untouched, so it doesn't work when offline

Answer (score 343):

[Wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) is a classic command-line tool for this kind of task. It comes with most Unix/Linux systems, and you can get it [for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/25538/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-wget/25540#25540) too. On a Mac, [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) is the easiest way to install it (`brew install wget`).

You'd do something like:

```
wget -r --no-parent http://example.com/songs/
```

For more details, see [Wget Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) and its [examples](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Examples), or e.g. these:

- [wget: Download entire websites easy](http://linuxreviews.org/quicktips/wget/)
- [Wget examples and scripts](http://www.krazyworks.com/?p=591)

Comment: There's no better answer than this - wget can do anything :3

Comment: +1 for including the --no-parent.  definitely use --mirror instead of -r.  and you might want to include -L/--relative to not follow links to other servers.

Comment: I don't think I've used --mirror myself so I didn't put it the answer. (And it's *not* really fully "self explanatory" like Paul's answer says...) If you want to elaborate on why it's better than -r I'd appreciate it!

Comment: As I also asked for httrack.com - would this cmd line tool get the ASP *code* or would it just get the rendering of the HTML?  I have to try this.  This could be a bit worrisome for developers if it does...

Comment: @optimal, the HTML output of course - it would get the code only if the server was badly misconfigured

Comment: unfortunately it does not work for me - there is a problem with links to css files, they are not changed to relative i.e., you can see something like this in files: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/reset.css" media="screen" /> which does not work locally well, unless there is a waz to trick firefox to think that certain dir is a root.

Comment: Homebrew shows how to install it right on their homepage http://brew.sh/

Comment: Httrack vs Wget? Which one should I use on a Mac?

Comment: @gorn That might be doable with a chroot, though I've never tried it.

Comment: Any chance of running this in parallel?

Comment: doesn't work with the links, images, and others, so it is useless. The other answer with command `wget -m -p -E -k www.example.com` did all the jobs and display a website locally with proper links, images, format, etc, in so easy way.

Comment: @BMW This should definitely be the top comment! I recommend adding this to the answer.

Comment: Diskernet it an alternative & works for single page applications & site that require authentication: https://github.com/i5ik/Diskernet

Comment: Is there any way to save the `JS` scripts separately than the html file? I also don't see any `CSS` files downloaded.

Answer (score 223):

Use wget:

```
wget -m -p -E -k www.example.com
```

The options explained:

```
-m, --mirror            Turns on recursion and time-stamping, sets infinite 
                          recursion depth, and keeps FTP directory listings.
-p, --page-requisites   Get all images, etc. needed to display HTML page.
-E, --adjust-extension  Save HTML/CSS files with .html/.css extensions.
-k, --convert-links     Make links in downloaded HTML point to local files.
-np, --no-parent        Don't ascend to the parent directory when retrieving 
                        recursively. This guarantees that only the files below 
                        a certain hierarchy will be downloaded. Requires a slash 
                        at the end of the directory, e.g. example.com/foo/.
```

Comment: +1 for providing the explanations for the suggested options. (Although I don't think `--mirror` is very self-explanatory. Here's from the man page: "*This option turns on recursion and time-stamping, sets infinite recursion depth and keeps FTP directory listings. It is currently equivalent to -r -N -l inf --no-remove-listing*")

Comment: If you don’t want to download everything into a folder with the name of the domain you want to mirror, create your own folder and use the -nH option (which skips the host part).

Comment: What about if the Auth is required?

Comment: I tried using your `wget --mirror -p --html-extension --convert-links www.example.com` and it just downloaded the index. I think you need the `-r` to download the entire site.

Comment: for those concerned about killing a site due to traffic / too many requests, use the `-w seconds` (to wait a number of secconds between the requests, or the `--limit-rate=amount`, to specify the maximum bandwidth to use while downloading

Comment: @EricBrotto you shouldn't need both `--mirror` and `-r`. From the `wget` man page: "[--mirror] is currently equivalent to -r".

Comment: `-p` is short for `--page-requisites`, for anyone else wondering.

Comment: Using `wget` like this will not get files referenced in Javascript. For example, in `<img onmouseout="this.src = 'mouseout.png';" onmouseover="this.src = 'mouseover.png';" src="image.png">`  the images for mouseout and mouseover will be missed.

Comment: Does anybody know how can I use wget to get the large images of the listings on ebay? For example I want to get the large images from this link: http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2051542.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.X1974+stamps.TRS0&_nkw=1974+stamps&_sacat=0. To be more specific I want the images that are being displayed when you hover the mouse over the image.

Comment: For me it doesn't work as expected, it no recreate all links inside the page in order to be browseable offline

Comment: If you only want to download `www.example.com/foo`, use the `--no-parent` option.

Comment: This seems to get confused with some hyperlinks: /contact was converted to index.html?p=11 (which it also copied into the top level directory, even though contact/index.html was downloaded too)

Comment: Ah, these are apparently redirects in wordpress but not resolved by wget, and strangely used in the downloaded html when resolved in the original html (no `p=` link in the `a` tag).

Comment: If you want to output a site running locally, use `localhost:4000` (or whatever your port is) and not `127.0.0.1:<your-port>` or it won't work—at least it didn't for me. For some reason, it would only get the `index.html` files for each page in my site and not all the assets, css, etc.

Comment: `wget --no-parent --recursive --level=inf --span-hosts --page-requisites --convert-links --adjust-extension --no-remove-listing https://……/…… --directory-prefix=……`. There must be someone _needs_ this.

Comment: I would like to point out that "--span-host" (not --span-hosts) is an important tag to me that I spent some time finding! Without this, links and images that are not in the domain specified will not be backup-ed!

Comment: this worked where others (including accpeted answer) failed miserably.

Comment: Is there any way to save the `JS` scripts separately than the html file? I also don't see any `CSS` files downloaded.

Comment: wget worked better for me..

Comment: This worked better for me, especially with external images: `wget -E -H -k -K -p http://my-site.com`

Comment: `--convert-file-only` *This option converts only the filename part of the URLs, leaving the rest of the URLs untouched. This filename part is sometimes referred to as the "basename", although we avoid that term here in order not to cause confusion.*

Comment: `-K` `--backup-converted` *When converting a file, back up the original version with a .orig suffix.  Affects the behavior of -N.*

Answer (score 7):

[Internet Download Manager](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/) has a Site Grabber utility with a lot of options - which lets you completely download any website you want, the way you want it.

1. You can set the limit on the size of the pages/files to download
2. You can set the number of branch sites to visit
3. You can change the way scripts/popups/duplicates behave
4. You can specify a domain, only under that domain all the pages/files meeting the required settings will be downloaded
5. The links can be converted to offline links for browsing
6. You have templates which let you choose the above settings for you

[image]

The software is not free however - see if it suits your needs, use the evaluation version.

Answer (score 7):

You should take a look at [ScrapBook](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scrapbook/), a Firefox extension. It has an [in-depth capture mode](http://amb.vis.ne.jp/mozilla/scrapbook/feature1.php?lang=en#CaptureOptions).

[image]

Comment: No longer compatible with Firefox after version 57 (Quantum).

Comment: seems it is no longer available.

Comment: it is available on Classic addons archive https://ca-archive.us.to/storage/0/427/scrapbook-1.5.14-fx.xpi  However this addon just download single pages and has to be used on a firefox xul browser such as Palemoon or Basilisk.

Answer (score 7):

I like [Offline Explorer](http://www.metaproducts.com/mp/offline_explorer.htm).
It's a shareware, but it's very good and easy to use.

Comment: Very good and really easy to use windows software, in shareware mode it is able to download up to 2000 files which is enough for small websites.

Answer (score 4):

[Teleport Pro](http://www.tenmax.com/teleport/pro/home.htm) is another free solution that will copy down any and all files from whatever your target is (also has a paid version which will allow you to pull more pages of content).

Answer (score 3):

## [Power wget](https://swsblog.stanford.edu/blog/creating-static-copy-website)

While wget was already mentioned this resource and command line was so seamless I thought it deserved mention:
`wget -P /path/to/destination/directory/ -mpck --user-agent="" -e robots=off --wait 1 -E https://www.example.com/`

[See this code explained on explainshell](http://www.explainshell.com/explain?cmd=wget+-P+%2Fpath%2Fto%2Fdestination%2Fdirectory%2F+-mpck+--user-agent%3D%22%22+-e+robots%3Doff+--wait+1+-E+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F)

Answer (score 2):

Try [BackStreet Browser](http://www.spadixbd.com/backstreet/).

> It is a free, powerful offline browser. A high-speed, multi-threading
>   website download and viewing program. By making multiple simultaneous
>   server requests, BackStreet Browser can quickly download entire
>   website or part of a site including HTML, graphics, Java Applets,
>   sound and other user definable files, and saves all the files in your
>   hard drive, either in their native format, or as a compressed ZIP file
>   and view offline.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For Linux and OS X: I wrote [grab-site](https://ludios.org/grab-site/) for archiving entire websites to [WARC](http://www.archiveteam.org/index.php?title=The_WARC_Ecosystem) files.  These WARC files can be [browsed](https://github.com/ludios/grab-site#viewing-the-content-in-your-warc-archives) or extracted.  grab-site lets you control which URLs to skip using regular expressions, and these can be changed when the crawl is running.  It also comes with an extensive [set of defaults](https://github.com/ludios/grab-site/blob/master/libgrabsite/ignore_sets/global) for ignoring junk URLs.

There is a web dashboard for monitoring crawls, as well as additional options for skipping video content or responses over a certain size.

Answer (score 1):

> #### *How can I download an entire website?*

Here is an example on how to download not an entire website, but just a *subdomain*, including all *its* subdomains :

```bash
wget -E -k -m -np -p https://www.mikedane.com/web-development/html/
```

This worked just fine. <sup>1</sup>

Apparently, this doesn't always get all the subdomains or PDFs, but it did get a fully functional copy that works fine offline.

Here are the meanings of the flags used, according to
[the Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) : <sup>2</sup>

`-E`   – will cause the suffix `.html` to be appended to the local filename 
`-k`   – converts the links to make them suitable for local viewing 
`-m`   – turns on recursion and time-stamping, infinite recursion depth 
`-np` – only the files *below* a certain hierarchy will be downloaded 
`-p`   – download all files necessary to properly display the pages

### Reference

- [wget(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget)

---

<sup>1</sup>
If you try it, expect the download to be about 793 KiB. 
In a previous version, I had `index.html` at the end of the URL.
This is unnecessary. It might even make the download fail.
But the ending forward slash, `/`, should *not* be left out.

<sup>2</sup>
Concerning the `-np` flag, the exception is when there are *dependencies* outside the hierarchy. 
For example, I made a download for which the referred CSS files are in a different subdomain. 
Yet, the subdomain that has the CSS files was also downloaded, which is what we want, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below free online tools which will make a zip file of all contents included in that URL:

- https://web2zip.com/
- https://www6.waybackmachinedownloader.com/website-downloader-online/

Answer (score 0):

[Cyotek WebCopy](https://www.cyotek.com/cyotek-webcopy) seems to be also a good alternative.
For my situation, trying to download a DokuWiki site, it currently seems to lack support for CSRF/SecurityToken.
Thats why I actually went for [Offline Explorer](https://metaproducts.com/products/offline-explorer) as stated already in [answer](https://superuser.com/a/42433/261493) above.

Answer (score 0):

**A1 Website Download** for Windows and Mac is yet another option. The tool has existed for nearly 15 years and has been continuously updated. It features separate crawl and download filtering options with each supporting pattern matching for "limit to" and "exclude".

Comment: This one works fine for me. It works even with sites that requires log in.

Answer (score -1):

The venerable **[FreeDownloadManager.org](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/)** has this feature too.

Free Download Manager has it in two forms in two forms: [Site Explorer and Site Spider](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/features.htm):

> **Site Explorer** 
> Site Explorer lets you view the folders structure of a
> web site and easily download necessary files or folders. 
> **HTML Spider**
> You can download whole web pages or even whole web sites with HTML
> Spider. The tool can be adjusted to download files with specified
> extensions only.

I find Site Explorer is useful to see which folders to include/exclude before you attempt attempt to download the whole site - especially when there is an entire forum hiding in the site that you don't want to download for example.

Answer (score -5):

I believe google chrome can do this on desktop devices, just go to the browser menu and click save webpage.

Also note that services like pocket may not actually save the website, and are thus susceptible to link rot.

Lastly note that copying the contents of a website may infringe on copyright, if it applies.

Comment: A web *page* in your browser is just one out of many of a web *site*.

Comment: @Arjan I guess that makes my option labor intensive. I believe it is more common for people to just want to save one page, so this answer may be better for those people who come here for that.