# How to download files from command line in Windows like wget or curl

Tags: windows, wget, curl

How can I download something from the web directly without Internet Explorer or Firefox opening Acrobat Reader/Quicktime/MS Word/whatever?

I'm using Windows, so a Windows version of [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) would do.

Comment: Just right clicking a file and hitting "Save Target As" or "Save Link As" or "Save As" (language varies depending on your browser) will work.

Comment: The point of having a command is being able to write a batch file and run it (perhaps scheduled as a task) anytime you want. That's where the GUI falls short.

Comment: How do you download with MS Word?

Comment: @JaimeHablutzel Why would you ever want to download something via MS Word? MS Word is not a terminal.

Comment: @B1KMusic look at the original question, I was having the same doubt as you

Comment: if a popup dialog for destination/open is ok that comes from the "auto-open-closed" Internet Explorer you could use `"%programfiles%/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe" http://foo.bar/somefile` (should work on many systems)

Comment: It's 2016 - make sure you scroll down to the answers that say "Powershell".  (Exactly the built-in solution you want when you're IE-restricted and you're trying to avoid installing random stuff on a client's servers...)

Comment: Here is a good article on using curl in PowerShell:  http://thesociablegeek.com/azure/using-curl-in-powershell/

Comment: @SDsolar Or just upvote/improve [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/25538/how-to-download-files-from-command-line-in-windows-like-wget-is-doing/494009#494009) below.

Comment: Roger that.  I did so, with complete instructions that will work with any modern version of Windows - no additions or modifications are required.

Answer (score 221, accepted):

[**Wget for Windows**](http://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/) should work.

From the [Wget Wiki FAQ](http://wget.addictivecode.org/FrequentlyAskedQuestions):

> GNU Wget is a free network utility to retrieve files from the World
>   Wide Web using HTTP and FTP, the two most widely used Internet
>   protocols. It works non-interactively, thus enabling work in the
>   background, after having logged off.

From [this section of FAQ](http://wget.addictivecode.org/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#download), download links are suggested:

> Windows Binaries
>
> - courtesy of Jernej Simončič: http://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/
> - from sourceforge: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm
> - [...]

Link with courtesy of Jernej Simončič is used instead.

Comment: There's also Winwget http://www.cybershade.us/winwget/ if you prefer a gui

Comment: The standalone version is downloadable from [this link](http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/).

Comment: More recent, even up-to-date (as of today) [Windows builds](https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/), provided by Jernej Simončič

Comment: @VitoShadow broken link

Comment: Sorry, [can no longer trust source forge downloads](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2929732/open-source-software/sourceforge-commits-reputational-suicide.html)

Comment: @cixelsyd Updated link to alternative source.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20150115044318/http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget

Comment: `wget https://unsecure-cert-site.com/page.html --no-check-certificate -O outputfile.html` to get around https issues.

Comment: There is no need to download anything.  See https://superuser.com/questions/25538/how-to-download-files-from-command-line-in-windows-like-wget-is-doing/494009#494009 below for instructions on how to make this work in native PowerShell.

Comment: eternallybored.org/misc/wget/ is flagged by enterprise antivirus on my system. Carbon Black / Bit 9. Probably false positive. But sourceforge one runs. Does not support sslv3.

Comment: sorry, but it is slower than google chrome download it downloads 200MB file in 9min and does the same with chrome in2 min ;)

Comment: how I wget the wget command if I don't have wget on my windows ?

Comment: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/e8fbec25db4f9d95b5e8f41cca51a4b32be8674a4dea7a45b6f7aeb22dbc38db/community

Comment: Bla, this is not the right answer for me!

Answer (score 380):

An alternative I discovered recently, using PowerShell:

```
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadFile("http://www.xyz.net/file.txt","C:\tmp\file.txt")
```

It works as well with GET queries.

If you need to specify credentials to download the file, add the following line in between:

```
$client.Credentials =  Get-Credential
```

A standard windows credentials prompt will pop up. The credentials you enter there will be used to download the file. You only need to do this once for all the time you will be using the $client object.

Comment: You can also do it in one-line: `(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://www.xyz.net/file.txt','C:\tmp\file.txt')`

Comment: That would be nothing like wget at all if only for the fact you have to install another large program just to use it.

Comment: @Rob powershell is built in to Windows...

Comment: From Vista up, yes.

Comment: Re @Arran: "From Vista up, yes" -- so... for the last six years (going on 7 now), yes, this has been built into Windows.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83, absolutely, but many, *many*, people are still using XP. It's merely something to bear in mind.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83, you underestimate the amount of people still on older Windows systems. I don't understand the issue, I pointed out it's only on Vista upwards. People can choose to ignore it, or say "hey thanks!", but you....? If you have an issue, create a chat and we can talk. Someone with rep (like you) should realise *here* is not the place for this discussion.

Comment: I'm just pointing out the clarification is a bit silly as it's been built into windows as long as it has existed -- and all currently supported versions of Windows have it built in.  Nothing further.

Comment: What if you need authentication for an https site AND you are behind a proxy?

Comment: Is there an option to see the progress of the download?

Comment: I'm not sure if this changed in some version of Powershell, but you can not specify a path for the second parameter of DownloadFile (you can only specify a filename). So if the above doesnt work for you, try: `(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://www.example.net/file.‌​txt','file.tx‌​t')`

Comment: Wget is build into powershell,  useless.

Comment: // , To my surprise, wget is built into PowerShell. But I'm pretty sure it doesn't work the same as in Linux.

Comment: `wget` in PowerShell is an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest`. Try running `Get-Alias wget`...

Comment: baby this is what I came for

Comment: Simpy use in PowerShell `wget https://myurl.com -OutFile myurl-result.html`

Comment: @BrainSlugs83: almost no one is using Win XP; almost everyone have migrated either to Win 10 or Ubuntu

Comment: This is the correct and SELECTED answer for me! Thanks!!

Answer (score 204):

### cURL

Windows 10 includes `curl.exe`:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/containers/-/ba-p/382409

so you can do something like this:

```sh
# example 1
curl.exe --output index.html --url https://superuser.com
# example 2
curl.exe -o index.html https://superuser.com
```

If you have older Windows, you can still download it:

https://curl.haxx.se/windows

### PowerShell

```sh
# example 1
Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile index.html -Uri https://superuser.com
# example 2
iwr -outf index.html https://superuser.com
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest

Comment: This doesn't work with redirects on sourceforge (and possibly other sites), as opposed to `System.Net.WebClient`. However you can make `Invoke-WebRequest` work by adding `-UserAgent [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PSUserAgent]::FireFox`.

Comment: The powershell part is the only one working  in Server 2016 core mode. Note that you need to specify the `securityprotocol` like https://stackoverflow.com/a/48030563/350580 to make https acturally work

Answer (score 80):

It's possible to [download a file with certutil](https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/A+Suspicious+Use+of+certutilexe/23517/):

```
certutil.exe -urlcache -split -f "https://download.sysinternals.com/files/PSTools.zip" pstools.zip
```

Certutil is not installed by default on XP/Win2003 but is avaialble on the newer windows versions.For XP/2003 you'll need the [Admin Tool Pack for windows server 2003](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=16770)

---

Old answer:

Windows has its own command line download utility - [BITSAdmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_Intelligent_Transfer_Service#Tools):

> BITSAdmin is a command-line tool that you can use to create download
> or upload jobs and monitor their progress.

[Here's my overview of how a file can be downloaded on windows without external tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143160/how-can-i-download-a-file-with-batch-file-without-using-any-external-tools)

And a complete bitsadmin example:

```
bitsadmin /transfer myDownloadJob /download /priority normal http://downloadsrv/10mb.zip c:\10mb.zip
```

Comment: Interesting.  That is one clumsy piece of software compared to wget.

Comment: Note that It doesn't ship with Windows XP, and maybe not with other versions either.

Comment: Update: BITSAdmin is deprecated and is not guaranteed to be available in future versions of Windows.
Administrative tools for the BITS service are now provided by BITS PowerShell cmdlets.

Comment: @MattH: because it's nto suppsoed to be wget in the first place? - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_Intelligent_Transfer_Service

Comment: Unable to add file - 0x80070057

Comment: Thank you for providing a native solution. Obviously wget is "like" wget...

Comment: I think you can not use relative paths, fx "foo.zip", you must use absolute paths like "C:\Users\jdoe\foo.zip". Otherwise you get "Unable to add file - 0x80070057 - The parameter is incorrect".

Comment: @MadsSkjern - yes with bitsadmin you cannot use relative paths. One workarround is to add `%cd%` to target location if you want to be relative to the current location.

Comment: On Windows 10, using certutil to download files sometimes causes Defender to block it as a Trojan:Win32/Ceprolad.A

Answer (score 38):

Save the following text as `wget.js` and simply call

```
cscript /nologo wget.js http://example.com
```

This is the code:

```
var WinHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1");
WinHttpReq.Open("GET", WScript.Arguments(0), /*async=*/false);
WinHttpReq.Send();
WScript.Echo(WinHttpReq.ResponseText);

/* To save a binary file use this code instead of previous line
BinStream = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
BinStream.Type = 1;
BinStream.Open();
BinStream.Write(WinHttpReq.ResponseBody);
BinStream.SaveToFile("out.bin");
*/
```

Comment: What language is this script in?Looks useful to my current task. I'd like to find more reference documentation. Doesn't look quite like vb

Comment: Useful for single files. Needs enhancing for recursive download and https.

Comment: @G-. I'm late to the party, but that's JavaScript.

Comment: I tried to do that for http://database.clamav.net/daily.cvd, but it downloaded only 88kB of 44MB :(

Answer (score 26):

There is a native cURL for Windows available [here](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html). There are many flavors available- with and without SSL support.

You don't need the extra baggage of [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) and the likes, just one small EXE file.

---

**It is also important to know that there are both `wget` and `curl` aliases built into all modern versions of Windows Powershell.  They are equivalent.**

**No extra files or downloads are required to obtain `wget` functionality:**

[Using Curl In Powershell](http://thesociablegeek.com/azure/using-curl-in-powershell/) (The Sociable Geek)

Excerpt:

> You can type in a cURL command like one that downloads a file from a
>   GitHub repository.
>
> curl http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/mongodb-on-ubuntu/azuredeploy.json
>
> and  it will seem like it works but what it is actually doing is just
>   using cURL as an alias. In the above instance, what will happen is
>   that you will just get the headers instead of the file itself.
>
> Aliases in PowerShell allow you to create shortcuts for longer commands so you don’t have to type them out all of the time.
>
> If you type in the command Get-Alias, it will give you a list of all the Aliases that are used in PowerShell. As you can see, the curl command just calls the Invoke-WebRequest command.  They are similar but not the same which is why the above request does not work for us.

[image]

To get this to work properly in PowerShell the easiest way is to use variables and the `-OutFile` argument as shown here:

[image]

> (file name cut off in image “https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/mongodb-on-ubuntu/azuredeploy.json”)

**This syntax will download the full contents of the target file `azuredeploy.json` to the local file `newfile.json`**

---

**The primary advantage is that it is built into Powershell itself so this code will execute directly with no downloads or any other extra file creations are required to make it work on any modern version of Windows.**

Comment: This be done directly on one line, but the line gets pretty long and is not as immediately readable at a glance.

Answer (score 25):

I made a quick myGet.bat file which calls the PowerShell method described above.

```
@Echo OFF
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set Var=%1
Set Var=!Var:http://=!
Set Var=!Var:/=,!
Set Var=!Var:%%20=?!
Set Var=!Var: =?!
Call :LOOP !var!
Echo.Downloading: %1 to %~p0!FN!
powershell.exe -Command (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('%1','%~p0!FN!')
GoTo :EOF
:LOOP
If "%1"=="" GoTo :EOF
Set FN=%1
Set FN=!FN:?= !
Shift
GoTo :LOOP
```

I borrowed some code from *[Parsing URL for filename with space](http://web.archive.org/web/20150813023444/http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/parsing-url-for-filename-with-space/14749.html)*.

Comment: why the downvote? this looks okay to me and is a direct response to the question. Yes it's clunky and could use improvement, like escaping ampersands (&) in the url, but it works as is.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just write a PowerShell script???

Comment: `powershell.exe -Command "Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile ./file-name https://location/file-name"` <-- Simple one line powershell usage in script file hard coding location and file name.

Answer (score 9):

I was searching for the same, and since I had no privilege to install any of the above packages, I went for a small workaround (to download 30+files):

- I created a batch file
- Listed all the files
- Put `firefox.exe` at the beginning of each line
- Went to the firefox directory in `Program Files`
- Ran it.

Answer (score 9):

You could also [use the `wget` packaged in PowerShell](https://superuser.com/a/693179/114388). ;^) To open, hit the Windows key and type "powershell" or Windows-R and type "powershell" and hit return.

No installation necessary.

One interesting difference from conventional `wget` (more at [that link](https://superuser.com/a/693179/114388)): You can't simply use the greater-than to pipe to a file. `wget` in PowerShell is just a convenience wrapper for `Invoke-WebRequest`, and you need to use its syntax to write to a file.

```
wget https://superuser.com/questions/25538 -OutFile rubySlippers.html
```

Comment: `-OutFile` did the job!

Answer (score 7):

If [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) is an option, that's the preferred route, since you (potentially) won't have to install anything extra:

```
(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://www.example.com/file.txt', 'C:\tmp\file.txt')
```

Failing that, Wget for Windows, as others have pointed out is definitely the second best option.  As posted in another answer it looks like you can [download Wget all by itself](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm), or you can grab it as a part of [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [MSys](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS).

If for some reason, you find yourself stuck in a time warp, using a machine that doesn't have PowerShell *and* you have zero access to a working web browser (that is, Internet Explorer is the only browser on the system, and its settings are corrupt), and your file is on an FTP site (as opposed to HTTP):

```
start->run "FTP", press "OK".
```

If memory serves it's been there since Windows 98, and I can confirm that it is still there in Windows 8 RTM (you might have to go into `appwiz.cpl` and add/remove features to get it). This utility can both download and upload files to/from FTP sites on the web. [It can also be used in scripts to automate either operation.](http://www.howtofixcomputers.com/forums/windows-xp/how-use-command-ftp-exe-windows-98176.html)

This tool being built-in has been a real life saver for me in the past, especially in the days of ftp.cdrom.com -- I downloaded Firefox that way once, on a completely broken machine that had only a dial-up Internet connection (back when sneakernet's maximum packet size was still 1.44 MB, and Firefox was still called "Netscape" */me does trollface*).

A couple of tips: it's its own command processor, and it has its own syntax. Try typing "help".  All FTP sites require a username and password; but if they allow "anonymous" users, the username is "anonymous" and the password is your email address (you can make one up if you don't want to be tracked, but usually there is some kind of logic to make sure it's a valid email address).

Comment: +1 for thinking of command line ftp! However wget and powershell were both mentioned well before you joined the party, so -1 there. :-/

Comment: The other powershell answers I saw were all multi-liners and/or had some code smell to them -- this is a short & simple one liner to download a file. -- Also I wanted to provide an answer that covered all the bases. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Search for `/download` function on https://lolbas-project.github.io.

Right now there are `Bitsadmin.exe`, `Certutil.exe`, `Esentutl.exe`, `Expand.exe, Extrac32.exe`,  `Findstr.exe`, `Hh.exe`, `Ieexec.exe`, `Makecab.exe`, `Replace.exe` for Windows vista, Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows 10  and the equivalent Server versions.

Answer (score 4):

[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) has Wget (and many more utilities).

Answer (score 4):

On Win CMD (if you have write access):

```
set url=https://www.nsa.org/content/hl-images/2017/02/09/NSA.jpg
set file=file.jpg
certutil -urlcache -split -f %url% %file%
echo Done.
```

Built in Windows app. No need for external downloads.

Tested on Win 10

Comment: Can you tell me where this file is being saved to?

Comment: The download will be saved to the file pointed to by variable `%file%`

Answer (score 3):

In Windows one can also use a Linux Terminal Emulator, like [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/), or [WSL2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).

The procedure is similar for both, what varies is the installation process.

For MobaXterm, this is the proceedure:

1. [Download and Install MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download.html) (the Home Edition may be enough for your use case).
2. Access MobApt (MobaXterm package manager) by opening the terminal and run `MobApt`.

[image: Access MobApt package manager]

3. Find the package `wget` and press `Install/Update` (assuming that it is still not installed).

[image: MobApt package manager for MobaXterm]

4. Then, run your script (I will leave at the bottom an example of a wget script that you may run).

For WSL2, this is the procedure:

1. Install WSL2 (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10). I'm using Ubuntu 18.
2. Once the setup is done, open and run the following command:

`sudo apt-get install wget`

3. Then run your script (I will leave at the bottom an example of a wget script that you may run).

---

You may use this script in both cases:

```
wget --header='Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,pt-PT;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7,de;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5,es;q=0.4,it;q=0.3,gl;q=0.2,hu;q=0.1' --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36" -c "http://..." -w 1
```

Answer (score 2):

And http://www.httrack.com/ has a nice GUI (and it's free), for mirroring sites. It also has a Linux version.

Answer (score 2):

I think installing `wget` via Chocolatey is the easiest way.

1. Install [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/)
2. From the command-line, type: `choco install wget`
3. You can then use `wget` from the command line like on *nix systems.

Answer (score 1):

You can get WGet for Windows [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm). Alternatively you can right click on the download link of the item you want to download and choose Save As. This will download the file and not open it in the assigned application.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a GUI, then try [VisualWget](https://sites.google.com/site/visualwget/a-download-manager-gui-based-on-wget-for-windows), which is actually clean, and feature full. It is based on GNU Wget for its download engine.

EDIT: updated link.

Comment: here is an updated link: https://sites.google.com/site/visualwget/a-download-manager-gui-based-on-wget-for-windows   (the downloads are at the bottom of the page, use the little arrows on the right)

Answer (score 1):

As documented in this [SU answer](https://superuser.com/a/387515/75184), you can use the following in Powershell:

```
Import-Module bitstransfer
start-bitstransfer -source http://something/something.ext -destination c:\something.ext
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using gnuwin32 is [unxutils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/) which includes wget.

Comment: you can manage with unxutils but it's old, it uses an old version of wget. gnuwin32 is the thing to use. not quite as convenient to install and not as easy to find things, but it has much more than unxutils too.

Answer (score -2):

If you need a **visual** Post for Windows, [here](http://www.soft.tahionic.com/download-windows_POST/index.html) is one.
You can post data or files with it.