# How do I install Wget for Windows?

Tags: windows-xp, installation, wget

[I downloaded Wget from here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget), and got a file named `wget-latest.tar.gz`, dated 22-Sep-2009. I saved it into one of the folders on my `D:` drive and unzipped it. I read through the `READ ME` file, but didn't find any information there on how to install it.  Since there was no `Install` file, I assumed that unzipping `wget.zip` into a previously created folder had installed it.

However, when I opened the command line and typed:

```
 wget -r -A ".jpg,.gif,.png" http://mywebsite
```

I only got an error message. Since I am using Chinese version of XP at the moment and I don't read Chinese, I don't understand what this message is saying, but I assume it means that Wget didn't install properly.

So, how do I properly install Wget on Windows XP?

Comment: See also [How to download files from command line in Windows like wget or curl](https://superuser.com/questions/25538/how-to-download-files-from-command-line-in-windows-like-wget-or-curl)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It sounds like you're using Windows. To download a pre-built wget.exe for Windows, see [WGET for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm).

In the box near the top of the page, `wget.exe` is a link to download the wget program itself. Since this is an exe file already, there's no need to unzip or install this particular version.

What you downloaded previously was the *source code* to wget, so you would need a compiler to build a wget for your system. This is probably not what you wanted.

Comment: Yay! we might be on the right track (after the third question)

Comment: Link is dead... See this newer answer: http://superuser.com/a/813046/23133

Comment: libintl3.dll not found?

Comment: After installation, it's located at: `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin`. You should add it to the `PATH` variable

Answer (score 10):

A pre-built binary 32-bit version of **wget** for Windows (currently version 1.11.4-1) can be found on **SourceForge** at:

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

You have the choice of downloading the **wget** package as a **setup program** or a **zip file**. As described on the SourceForge download page, here is the difference:

> If you download the **Setup program of the package**, any requirements
>   for running applications, such as dynamic link libraries (DLL's) from
>   the dependencies as listed below under Requirements, are already
>   included. If you download the **package as Zip files**, then you must
>   download and install the dependencies zip file yourself. Developer
>   files (header files and libraries) from other packages are however not
>   included; so if you wish to develop your own applications, you must
>   separately install the required packages.

I chose to install **wget** with the objective for checking for [broken links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15029100/1497596). Here is a bat file I created to drive **wget** to do so:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal
set Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin;%Path%
set TARGET=http://your.website.com/here.html

: http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html
:
: -e  --execute
: -o  --output-file
: -p  --page-requisites
: -r  --recursive
:     --spider
: -w  --wait

wget --spider -o wget.log -e robots=off --wait 1 -r -p %TARGET%

endlocal
```

I installed **wget** via its setup program on **Windows 7**. As you can see in the `PATH` variable in the bat file, the default installation location for **wget.exe** is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin
```

Comment: The versions maintained at this site are old and do not support newer versions of https.  Instead use: https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/

Answer (score 8):

You may want to also look into [cygwin](http://cygwin.com/). This allows you to manage windows totally from command line. With cygwin you can easily wget any file.

Comment: I use cygwin for wget.

Answer (score 7):

To actually "install" wget so that you can use it from any command prompt (as you attempted), you need to add its containing folder to the PATH environment variable. Proper practice would be to create a "Utilities" folder such as C:\Program Files\Utilities and adding it to the path, and then placing any utilities that do not come with an installer into here and adding it to the system path.

I however, tend to be lazy and simply drop the utilities into C:\Windows\System32 as it is already on the path and doesn't require a reboot to take effect. Use proper caution when working with the windows directory if you choose this route.

Comment: Changing PATH should not require a reboot. Just open a new command prompt, and it should take effect there.

Comment: it requires you to log in and log out (for the GUI) or to start a new command window. I just have a specific folder for tools i need in my path though

Comment: An "install" here was to drop the [latest binaries](https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/) (ver 12*) onto the desktop and use from there. The help file in the zip is a newer © than the [GNU Wget 1.20 Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) but much smaller in size.

Answer (score 2):

Download wget.exe from [https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/](http://C:%5CUsers%5Cmr_an%5CAppData%5CLocal%5CMicrosoft%5CWindowsApps) and then copy into your "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps" folder.  You'll get an up to date copy of wget and it will be on the path right away.

Comment: The exe file which I am getting here in not getting install in my machine. Any alternate?

Comment: No idea any more.