# what's the PC version of "wget -r" to get files off an ftp site in the command line?

Tags: windows, ftp, wget

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the windows equivalent of wget?](https://superuser.com/questions/25538/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-wget)

someone showed me a really quick way to get folders off an ftp site via the shell on a Mac using the command "wget -r ftp://" (then the address of the ftp site folder location) and it would download to whatever folder i was in, keeping all the sub directories the same as the ftp site

seemed really quick and easy, but how do i do a similar thing on a PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wget` is a linux program. It may seem like a *command* but in actuality it is just a handy little console application that you can invoke to download files from the web using the HTTP or FTP protocol. For Windows you will have to find a similar program to do the same from the command line..

Answer (score 2):

You can get [wget for Windows](http://pages.interlog.com/~tcharron/wgetwin.html).