# How do I neatly save a set of webpages?

Tags: download, webpage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I download an entire website](https://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website)

I have an index webpage, with just one level of links. I want to download all the linked webpages and have them neatly stored on my computer, so clicking the link on the index should open up the respective offline webpage. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest tool to use is [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/), it is a free, fast and an easy to use website copier that is **very** configurable. You can set links deep and pretty much anything you want.

It will store all the downloaded results in a folder and preserve the directory structure of the server.

You can then either browse offline by double clicking on any file or copy to a webserver and all links will be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to use [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) for this, using [recursive download](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Download.html#Recursive-Download) options