# Save Website To Disk

Tags: internet, website, download, archiving

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I download an entire website](https://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website)

Hello everyone!

I have a very poor internet connection when I'm living at home. The only time I have a good internet is at college. When I get home, the most mundane task like opening a web-page becomes a five minute stress-test.

So what I was thinking was to download the web-page, for example superdickery. I was wondering what the best method would be to download the entire image archive of the page?

Would this be illegal, if I did this? It's just that I don't want to be frustrated every time I just want to load a simple jpeg image.

Comment: potential duplicates: http://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website or http://superuser.com/questions/36125/how-do-i-neatly-save-a-set-of-webpages or http://superuser.com/questions/104488/how-to-recursively-download-an-entire-web-directory or http://superuser.com/questions/25538/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-wget ... or check [this search](http://superuser.com/search?q=%22wget%22+OR+[wget])

Answer (score 2):

on Unix machines you simply can use the recursive download feature of wget; on Windows there's HTTrack.

Hope, this helps, Klaus

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, Internet Explorer has File - Save As - Web Archive (Single File) .mht which will open with IE or Firefox. That's good for a single page. For the complete site, I've used [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) before.

Answer (score 0):

wget is a great tool. However, most of the time, I usually just right-click on the page and save the complete web page. If you use Firefox, you might also consider the add-on [DownloadThemAll](http://www.downthemall.net/) which gives you a lot of control over what you are downloading.

Answer (score 0):

What you would be doing would in practice be **caching**.

**Caching** is not illegal: if it was, *every* person using a computer is committing a crime.

Finally, if some weird law-maker stated that normal browser **cache** is not illegal but doing with `wget` is, then the laws would be so stupid and irrational that you shouldn't worry about anything anyway (because you would have absolutely no way to know if *anything* is legal or not).