# How can I fetch the images of a public website using wget?

Tags: images, wget

How can I fetch the images of a public website using wget? It's not a huge site: it has about 40 pages, with around three images per page.

**I want to avoid:**

1. Manually downloading the images
2. Downloading the whole site

Any ideas?

Comment: I really want to do this to Stack Overflow and the SO Trilogy for their sick layout images, at sstatic.net.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use wget and tell it to only down image files or use  http://www.downthemall.net/

From http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/wget/wget_31.html

> You want to download all the GIFs from a directory on an HTTP server. You tried `wget http://www.server.com/dir/*.gif', but that didn't work because HTTP retrieval does not support globbing. In that case, use:
>
> ```
> wget -r -l1 --no-parent -A.gif http://www.server.com/dir/
> ```

More verbose, but the effect is the same. `-r -l1' means to retrieve recursively (see section 3. Recursive Retrieval), with maximum depth of 1.`--no-parent' means that references to the parent directory are ignored (see section 4.3 Directory-Based Limits), and `-A.gif' means to download only the GIF files.`-A "*.gif"' would have worked too.

Comment: That's the spirit!! Why can't I upvote you?...

Comment: you'll need 15 karma points to cast a vote ... but i can :) +1

Answer (score 1):

I write a util named ifetch, you can try it.
http://sourceforge.net/p/ifetch/wiki/Home/

Answer (score 0):

[**Online Images Batch Download 1.1.0**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9483) (Firefox Addon)

Answer (score 0):

see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website/42379#42379).

The second template is **all pictures of the website**. I guess thats what you wanted?