# Mass downloading a set of URLs with login

Tags: download, download-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I download an entire website](https://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website)

I'm looking a mass-downloader to help me download the entire database from a site I have an account on. The requirements are simple:

1. Login using my user and password (form-based login)
2. Download all URLs of the form "http://site.com/ID", where ID is less than 1000.

What should I use?

Comment: Wow, so many answers, so little upvotes on any of them (0 upvoted answers so far).

Comment: How is this the same as downloading an entire site? I don't want to follow links, I want to download a set of links of a specific form.

Comment: Comparing these answers to the listed duplicate, they are all listing exactly the same answers provided to this question. Therefore it is a duplicate. Most of the software listed on the duplicate allows this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

[GetGo Download Manager](http://www.getgosoft.com/) seems to do that:

> You can easily set up a Batch Download
>   that not only downloads a large list
>   of files using an URL pattern
>   template, but also automatically
>   renames downloaded files using a
>   filename pattern template.

Answer (score 1):

I strictly recommend [**NeoDownloader**](http://www.neowise.com/neodownloader/). I've been using it for years.

It downloads from password protected sites and supports downloading URL ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Try [**Orbit Downloader**](http://www.orbitdownloader.com/).  MANY options available with that.

Answer (score 0):

I have had good luck with [Offline Explorer](http://www.metaproducts.com/mp/offline_explorer.htm). Allows you to access password protected pages and has lots of advanced options.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/), and possibly a very simple script (depending on how the site is set up).

Answer (score 0):

[HTTRACK](http://www.httrack.com/) works like a champ for copying the contents of an entire site. This tool can even grab the pieces needed to make a website with active code content work offline.

[image]