# Download full web page: css, js, images and one or more levels of links

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, javascript, export

I am trying to download a web page including everything. I tried several methods and so far what worked better is the build in save page in Firefox, nevertheless it does not allow me to include one or more levels of links. I also tried HTTrack but in this case it fails to include the js files.

How can I configure [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) to download js as well? A better tool to do this?

Thanks

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/341960/how-do-you-use-wget-to-mirror-a-site-1-level-deep-recovering-js-css-resources?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rip a website via HTTP to download images, HTML and CSS](http://superuser.com/questions/130306/rip-a-website-via-http-to-download-images-html-and-css)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I download an entire website?](https://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website)

Answer (score 1):

If you on Mac, install brew, then use brew to install wget, finally, use wget command to download the page.

```
wget -p -k -e robots=off -U 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US;rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070802 SeaMonkey/1.1.4' https://www.google.com
```

Comment: `wget` is also available for Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

On the web page , view its source , and then copy it and paste it in notepad and for others open those css and js links from the website's source  and save according to their file-extension.

Comment: This sounds very time consuming and error prone

Comment: Get a stone tablet and chisel, and make a manual copy of the webpage...