# Download all the links from a website at once

Tags: website, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I download an entire website](https://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website)

Is there any software that allows you to download all the links of a website at once?

E.g.: I'm using the w3school.com site and want to download all the PHP tutorials at once.

Someone told me "tglepote".bt I have no idea what it is and Google returns me with nothing.

Comment: i would strongly discourage "download all the link at once" as it can strain the web server in question (if implemented poorly). Why not just peruse the content online?

Comment: Not really a SO question at all, but you could try wget or the Down Them All extension for Firefox.

Comment: @random: I submit that this question is not a dupe.  The OP is not asking how to download an entire site, but rather how to extract certain files (e.g., all the .pdf files) from that site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/):

> GNU Wget is a free software package for retrieving files using HTTP, HTTPS and FTP, the most widely-used Internet protocols. It is a non-interactive commandline tool, so it may easily be called from scripts, cron jobs, terminals without X-Windows support, etc.

Comment: You'd better explain how to use the command for the needs of the OP, since it has hundreds of options.

Answer (score 11):

wget --mirror --no-parent http://..../the.page.html

Answer (score 1):

I've had decent luck with the "DownThemAll" extension for firefox:
http://www.downthemall.net/

Comment: That's fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

[Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/) has that functionality.