# Program to read and convert entire website to html

Tags: software-rec, conversion, html, cms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I download an entire website](https://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website)

I'm using a very old cms, Synkron.web. I need to convert all of my pages (written in .asp) to plain html - so I have an archive where all of the pages from my website are saved.

I was wondering if there isnt some kind of program out there for Windows XP, with the ability to traverse all documents on a website, view their source, and save them as html-pages on my local machine?

If not, do you have any suggestions on how to convert a Synkron.web database, to some kind of open-source CMS? Like Wordpress, etc...

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you using?

If it's Windows then [WinHTTrack](http://www.httrack.com) is very good and highly customisable in its spidering rules.

Comment: Windows XP - edited my question to include this info.

WinHTTrack looks exactly like something I wanted - I'll give it a try!