# Command-line HTTP crawler for Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, website, web-crawler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I download an entire website](https://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website)

Would somebody have a recommendation for a web site crawler that can be invoked and equipped with settings from the command line?

This would need to run in a Windows environment.

Saving the data, following stylesheet links etc. is not an issue. I only need the crawler to start with a page, parse it, and follow all the links on the same domain so that in the end, all pages on the site have been requested once.

Background: I'm setting up a web site that gets frequently uploaded from an office location. Combining data from various sources, it has several levels of caching. I don't want the first user to visit the site after a fresh upload to have to wait until the page has been generated and saved in the cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`wget`](http://www.christopherlewis.com/WGet/WGetFiles.htm) `--mirror`

Comment: wget continues to surprise me :D cheers, will try this first.