# How to download all files from a site?

Tags: download, website

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I download an entire website](https://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website)

There is a site, which has shared images on it, but I know the urls to only some of them. I suppose there are hundreds of images on this site and I want to download them all.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I download an entire website](http://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website) and it includes how to get all images from a website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you try wget, the "non-interactive downloader". It is a command-line file/website/whatever downloading utility packed with features. I have easily mirrored (ie. completely downloaded) several sites to my hard drive with it. Don't shrug it off because it is a "command-line" program, it's very easy to use.

You haven't mentioned what operating system you are using. If it's a *nix-like system you can probably install wget through your package manager. If it's Windows, you can get a Windows of it version here:

```
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm
```

I think this wget command should do it for you:

```
wget --page-requisites --convert-links --html-extension --restrict-file-names=windows  www-example-dot-com
```

With you replacing the website's address where I wrote www-example-dot-com

If you are completely baffled:

The program's name (wget, of course), along with a list of options ("arguments") is typed at the command line. `--page-requisites` option tells it to download everything the page needs to show up propperly, such as the images on it. --convert-links makes it possible to browse the local copy offline. `--html-extension` and `--restrict-file-names=windows` help make the thing viewable offline on most computers (in a nutshell).

If you want to download (mirror) the entire site to your hard drive, check out the `--recursive` and `--level options`.

I'm not going to explain working with the command line in full, but if you don't know: it becomes very easy once you grasp opening a command prompt and then changing directories. (honest!) You could of course rather look for a GUI-based download manager or something, but it might just nag you to register, unlike wget, which is open source.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few programs catered to do so. As long as the images are found on the same page. Here's one program I just found through a quick search:

http://www.exisoftware.com/news/download-all-images-from-a-website.html

Comment: Does not work, I mean the site has no links to the images and directory browsing is disabled. It's on an apache server.

Comment: Well, like I said. Just look for other programs that you think would support it. There's also downthemall for Firefox: http://blogs.techrepublic.com.com/security/?p=62