# Seeking a tool to pull an entire tree of webpages with some selection options

Tags: software-rec, download, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I download an entire website](https://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website)

I frequently encounter webpages that offer manual pages or other info accessible only via a table of contents consisting of links to individual chapters or paragraphs. Often the individual leaf pages then consist of a few lines only, so traversing the entire tree is extremely cumbersome.

What I am seeking is a tool that would allow me to pull and combine all pages referenced by the links of a starting page into a single concatenated html document, such that one could e.g., save that page and/or linearly scroll through all child pages without having to click and go back 1000 times. This would also allow to print the entire collection to have a manual or search through it in one go, etc.

Does anyone know a good tool to achieve that? Ideally such a tool would offer some exclusion criteria (like ignore all "back" links or the link to help or home pages that is found on each page, etc.).

Comment: The tool that can download the complete tree of the web-site is [browse-offline.com](http://www.browse-offline.com)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) in mirror mode:

```
C:\MySites\> wget -m http://mymanuals.com/manuals/foobar
```

Would mirror the whole http://mymanuals.com/manuals/foobar site.

The other thing I have used with quite good success is [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/page/2/) which again mirrors a website for you, but with a nice GUI front-end.

Comment: I was about to suggest HTTrack, but you beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

[`wget`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/) to get all the pages. You could use [xhtml2pdf](http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/) and [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) to create a single document.

Comment: I don't think is is a duplicate! I am NOT trying to duplicate an entire website. What I would rather like to see is some tool, that lists a website's structure and pages e.g. as a tree and one can then conveniently select (e.g. by checking or circling) those which one wants to be copied (i.e. concatenated and "flattened") into a single document. IMHO that's a different job from just duplicating a website to local.