# Is it possible to cache an entire website for offline use on a tablet device?

Tags: android, ipad, tablet

A friend of mine wants to build a website which allows the user to access various images, audio clips and videos. She would ideally like to be able download/cache the entire website to a tablet device so that it can be smoothly and reliably used while offline. Is this possible?

Comment: This could be a slightly different question (albeit one your friend might be able to direct her visitors to the answer for) but: it'd be really useful to know of a way to download all the local HTML files (and associated CSS/image resources) linked from the home page of an arbitrary website. If you could do this, you could save that download to your Android device and browse the site locally even when offline.

Comment: There is some PC software that allows you to download entire websites: http://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website

Answer (score 3):

She could consider developing it in Adobe AIR and providing a downloadable runtime on the website itself.  May not be suitable if the site is often updated.

http://www.adobe.com/products/air/

It supports both PC based tablets, and Android and iOS devices, so should be quite flexible.

Comment: Thanks, it would not be frequently updated so that would work. Forgive my ignorance but is a "downloadable runtime" basically like a Flash website, where it needs to download but you get to view it on the website?

Comment: It is like running a website (with flash) in a window on your desktop.  People like Tweetdeck use it to write portable applications, but there's no theoretical reason why you couldn't run a local copy of a website in it.