# File format to save web pages

Tags: flash, website, save-as

Usually I save web pages to later (mostly offline) reading in PDF format. It's really easy to transfer to anywhere, And the results are nice. I've installed Primo PDF to that.

I found a website with some little flash guidances, that I want "to embed" to my saved webpages, and (until where I know) PDF doesn't store flash movies.

What format do you suggest to save the web page to later offline reading, preserving the flash movies?

PS: (I know the fact that some flash movies are protected to copy/leech/etc. I sure that flash movies in the website that I want to save are "xcopy-able")  :)

Comment: Related: [How can I download an entire website?](http://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want the full site just some specific page. Because that I used PDF before...

Comment: I know, that's why I only said "related" :) -- it's not only about the full site though. The top software recommended is something you might want to check out.

Comment: "some flash movies are protected to copy/leech/etc" is nonsense. Your browser must download the movie in order to show it, which means you can download it too. 99% of such "protections" can be defeated with `wget --referer` or `curl -e`.

Comment: @grawity nonsense? Do you have tryed download some flash game in that big websites? It's a movive that loads another movie, and another, ...