# How to download all HTML pages in a website

Tags: browser, download, http

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I download an entire website?](https://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website)

If there is a website `www.example.com`, there are many static pages with same name under different paths.

Is there any way to download all the pages to view them offline?

For example:

```
www.example.com/a/x.page
www.example.com/b/x,page
www.example.com/b/c/x,page
```

I want to do this since I can't access internet at home, only at our company office.

Answer (score 6):

I've used http://www.httrack.com/ it's an excellent tool that will take a dynamic site and download it to a local directory so you can browse it offline.

Comment: Agree, using both WinHTTrack (GUI version for Windows) and WebHTTracks (GUI for linux) and I was always satisfied.

Comment: I use wget, but httrack is definitely easier.

Answer (score 6):

If you have `wget` installed, it's a one-liner:

```
wget -mk -w 20 http://www.example.com/
```

[GNU WGet](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)

[WGet for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)