# Script or program to download all images in a folder

Tags: images, perl, download

I'm currently using windows 7, and I was wondering if there is perhaps a perl script or a program I can install to download files from a given directory. For example, I want to be able to specify that it is in this directory

.../files/txt/

And then give it a pattern to search for, so have it download all the files that start with the prefix "xz_" and the suffix ".txt"

.../files/txt/xz_*.txt

Would like a versatile program, if I need a different extension, then I want to be able to specify it.

Thanks!

Comment: by download, do you mean copy?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I download an entire website?](http://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website)

Answer (score 1):

[wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) (for windows - not perl, but still CLI) is your friend.