# How to download website for offline viewing with custom parameters for downloading?

Tags: website, download-manager, offline-files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I download an entire website?](https://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website)

I want to download this website for offline viewing. Basically the site has open source projects demonstration and the source for the code is on GitHub. I want to download website for offline viewing and also source from GitHub. Is there any software for this?
The name of the site is http://cocoacontrols.com

UPDATE:
Hey can any one tell me step by step settings to download the website I mentioned in my question. I am having trouble running httrack.

Comment: already answered here: http://serverfault.com/questions/45096/website-backup-and-download

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to look into [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/page/1/en/index.html). It's a free utility, and I am sure you'll like it. :)

Comment: This is for windows machine is there any for MAC OS X?

Comment: There's tarball for `Linux/OSX/BSD/Unix sources version
WebHTTrack (also included: httrack, command line version)` on the [Download](http://www.httrack.com/page/2/) page

Comment: Hey can you tell me step by step settings to download the website I mentioned in my question. I am having trouble running httrack