# How can I download an entire (active) SMF2 forum?

Tags: wget, mirroring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I download an entire website?](https://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website)

I would like to download a full copy of a Simple Machines 2 Forum. I want to make a locally browsable copy of the entire forum. The forum is completely public, I can view all user profiles and forums without logging in.

Could someone say me how I would do it with this site for example?

http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php

I would like to use wget and copy really all sites from the forum. (Of course except member area etc)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why? That's a big forum. What could be the point in that, if your internet works?

Comment: @ekaj, perhaps offline access?

Comment: @soandos - Right. markus, see http://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website

Comment: @studiohack How is that off topic if the question has already been asked before?

Comment: @ekaj whoops! my bad. corrected - thanks for letting me know! :)