# Utility to download a full webpage for Mac

Tags: mac, software-rec, download, webpage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I download an entire website?](https://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website)

I need to download a full webpage (single domain) with images and working links for offline use. I've found a few utilities to do so, but none which works on mac. Do you have any suggestions for a good tool?

Comment: Please note that a *web page* is a single document, whereas a *web site* is a collection of documents. You're probably asking for the latter..?

Answer (score 1):

Here maybe this will help :

http://www.sitesucker.us/mac/mac.html

SiteSucker can be used to make local copies of Web sites. By default, SiteSucker "localizes" the files it downloads, allowing you to browse a site offline, but it can also download sites without modification.

Or this :

http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/6857/web-dumper

Answer (score 0):

In safari,

Choose File -> Save As

Click the Format pop-up menu to choose the format for the saved page. Choose Web Archive (which saves all) (or page source if you only want HTML).

Answer (score 0):

**HtTrack** is such a tool but I would recommend it for power users as the options are pretty detailed. http://www.httrack.com/