# Saving website before host shuts down

Tags: website

I created two websites for a local football team with news and photos, etc. I created them on a hosting facility provided by a newspaper company for amateur sports clubs. After ten years they now inform me that their hosting service will end in one month's time. They advise me to make arrangements to preserve the two sites if I wish keep the content, as the sites will not be available after the hosting service ends. How can I save these sites for future referencing ?

Comment: How were the files uploaded to their site? If they were uploaded via something like ftp then you can use that same method to download them. If they were uploaded and edited via a web interface then that would lend itself to other answers.

Comment: If you have a problem archiving the site, if no one else can help, and if you can find them, maybe you can call on the [ArchiveTeam](http://www.archiveteam.org/).

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website)

If you just want a copy of the website you could use a program called [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/).  Which is just a website ripper.