# Mirror a blog with wget

Tags: wget, mirroring

I am trying to mirror a blog, eg `www.example.com`, with `wget`.

I use wget with the following options (shell variables are substituted correctly):

```
wget -m -p -H -k -E -np \
    -w 1 \
    --random-wait \
    --restrict-file-names=windows \
    -P $folder \
    -Q${quota}m \
    -t 3 \
    --referer=$url \
    -U 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070802 SeaMonkey/1.1.4' \
    -e robots=off \
    -D $domains
    -- $url
```

The blog contain images that reside on other domains.

Even though I have specified the `-p` option (download linked page assets) these images are not being downloaded unless I specify each domain explicitly in the `-D` option.

If I omit the `-D` option then wget will follow every link outside `www.example.com` and download the whole internet.

Is it possible for `wget` to just follow every link under `www.example.com` and download each page’s required assets, whether those reside on the same domain or not without me having to specify each domain explicitly?

Comment: I'd love to find a good answer to this one also. I've run into the same situation and couldn't find a single wget invocation that did it. I ended up using `wget -N -E -H -k -K -p` first, and came up with a script to fetch missing linked images.

Comment: According to [this one](http://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website/14436#14436), [httrack](http://www.httrack.com/) is a killer for this. I'll give it a shot next time instead of wget.

Comment: Assuming your blog (minus the page assets) is not spanning multiple domains, try removing both the `-D $domains` as well as `-H`. Without `-H` it should stay within your domain but still retrieve the direct page assets, even when they are on a different domain.

Answer (score 1):

No, the only way is to specify the domains that you want wget to follow using -D or --domains=[domain list] (in the form of comma separated list)