# Printable version of whole site

Tags: pdf, website

I want a printable version of a whole site. I have read [How can I download an entire website?](https://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website/) 
and similar answers to download a site, but I want every page as PDF (in my case, I want to save a Wordpress site). 
Any solutions are welcome (download PDFs, or convert the local page I've already downloaded with HTTRACK to PDF).

Thank you!

Comment: Would this be good enough for you? http://pdfcrowd.com/

Comment: Hi @MC10 and thank you for your answer. I'm testing it right now, so far I could only convert 1 page at a time (I'm a Java developer, but was trying to avoid a programmed solution). I will keep this question updated.

Comment: An [add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/print-pages-to-pdf/) for Firefox.

Comment: Adobe Acrobat can do this (but it costs money).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have all the HTML, you can use [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/).

There is also a way to [batch convert](http://willchernoff.com/2014/10/13/batch-convert-html-files-to-pdf-with-wkhtmltopdf-in-mac-osx/), that sounds like what you're after. It should work on other systems even though the link says Mac OS X. You may want to change some of the options, so check out the [documentation](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt).

Comment: Thank you!!! The bach converter looks very promising. I'll let you know in a few hours!

Comment: Ok, I couldn't manage yet to get my "for" working, but that's another problem :D. It's working fine for a few pages. Thanks again @MC10 !

Answer (score 0):

Just go to "Print" (Ctrl+P on most OSes) and chose "print to PDF". At least on my Linix here I could do this ootb.
On Windows you might need a PDF-Printer.