# How can I download files on a webpage, when the download link is in a new tab?

Tags: download

This question doesn't duplicate [How can I download an entire website?](https://superuser.com/q/14403/269574), because that website directly contains the download links, whilst my webpage doesn't.

I aim to download all files simultaneously, without clicking on each link unproductively.

[image]

Comment: You have not actually stated why any of the answers in the duplicate do not work and as such this *is* a duplicate. Downloading an entire website *would* follow php links such as shown and would, from experience, correctly download links on subpages. Rather than an image you've written on, try actually using words to describe what you have tried, what the tools in the linked question failed to do and *describe your actual problem*.

Comment: Amongst the answers is httrack and several other full site downloaders. Try at least some of them and tell us what happens.