# How to download a webpage with all items contained in it?

Tags: download, html, webpage, web-application, html-files

I have been trying to download a web page which contains different items.We can access only one item at a time and have to click on the other item to browse that item. This is how is looks like:
[image: Source]
Currently the web page is showing question number 43. I have to click on the numbered icons present on the right hand side to browse the question corresponding to that numbered icon. I have got to download all these questions to my desktop. But it is hard to download them by browsing though every question and saving a copy of web page corresponding to it one by one. I need to find some way so I could download all these questions at once to save my time. Also, the website asks for login credentials for getting access to this web page.

This is my failed attempt to download the web page:
[image: Source 2]
In this downloaded web page, I cannot browse through other questions corresponding to different numbered icons. I click on them but it shows the static web page which I downloaded. Is these any solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: you may differ between

- download one page, what you can do simply (in Firefox) as "Save the the whole page";
- download some portion of server web tree; this can be done with either a Firefox plugin ScrapBook, or with some special programs (some of them are free)

The use of ScrapBook or Httrack has many parameters to be config.

See: [the similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/14403/)

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.