# How to download an entire apache directory

Tags: apache-http-server

Is there a way to download an entire apache directory, with all subfolders and files, to a local directory on my computer?

For example this:
http://onj3.andrelouis.com/phonetones/

This is an archive of phone ringtones, but rather than download every individual zip file in every individual folder, it would be way easier, if it was possible to download the entire directory to a folder on my computer. It would also be nice, if it could retain the original time stamps on the files, but I'm not even sure if apache stores this kind of data.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I download an entire website?](https://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is good old tool `Teleport Pro`. It does what you need and much more.

You can download the visible part of the website/folder structure. However on the server side it does look a little different, because what you see as a user with web browser is what Apache serves to you. What is stored on server may look a little different.

Edit for comments:

1. A little different, because on server `php` files are scripts, which you will see after execution.
2. Free are `curl` and `wget` - both available in Linux and also downloadable executables for Windows, you may want to use WSL in Windows for that.
3. Also there are web browsers add-ons which download all links on current webpage. Recursively too.

See also here:

[How can I download an entire website?](https://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website)

Comment: What do you mean by a little different. Will it perhaps download other files than I can see with a web browser, or will the folder structure be different, or is it something else? Also, what site would you suggest is best to download the tool from. I can't seem to find its "official" download site.

Comment: I just saw that it doesn't appear to be free. Do you know if there's a free alternative?

Comment: @akse0435 edited answer.